# What's wrong with my SQLite Statement? I keep getting a syntax error

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I keep getting the following error and I can't figure out why:

> 09-26 22:18:42.255: E/AndroidRuntime(10613): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       09-26 22:18:42.255: E/AndroidRuntime(10613):
>       android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException:     near ",": syntax error (code 1): ,

while  compiling:

```
UPDATE reminders
SET NAME = 'Finish this app.'
    , category = 'Personal'
    , priority = 'Urgent'
    , note = 'Test note'
    , phone_call = 0
    , text_message = 0
    , phone_number = ''
    , text_message_content = ''
    , no_reminder = 0
    , remind_me_after = 1
    , remind_me_after_length = 120
    , custom_remind_me_after = 0
    , remind_me_at = 0
    , time_hour = 22
    , time_minute = 18
    , date_month = 8
    , date_day = 26
    , date_year = 2012
    , recur = Never
    , custom_recur_length = 0
    , custom_recur_unit = NULL
    , custom_recur_until_month = 0
    , custom_recur_until_day = 0
    , custom_recur_until_year = 0
    , custom_recur_sunday = 0
    , custom_recur_monday = 0
    , custom_recur_tuesday = 0
    , custom_recur_wednesday = 0
    , custom_recur_thursday = 0
    , custom_recur_friday = 0
    , custom_recur_saturday = 0
    , share_email_address = ''
    , share_email_message = ''
    , share_phone_number = ''
    , share_text_message_content = ''
    , alert_type_sound = 1
    , alert_type_vibrate = 1
    , alert_type_notification_light = 1
    , repeat_alert = 0
    , repeat_alert_length = 0
    , repeat_alert_times = 0
WHERE _id = 8
```

Comment: My god is that an ugly statement. Can you please format it better?

Comment: recur = never ... is 'never' a string or some kind of constant? If it's a string, then it's missing parentheses.

Comment: recur =   Never
Should be 
recur =  'Never' i guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
recur = Never
```

Should be

```
recur = 'Never'
```

i guess

Answer (score 1):

> ```
>    recur = never,
> ```

This should be

```
   recur = 'never',
```